# Root.Js: how to pass parameters to THttpServer?

Tags: root-framework

I am using `root.js` and querying a fixed `TH2I` via JavaScript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var histo;
    JSROOT.httpRequest("https://subdomain.doamin.xx/root/Objects/subfolder/histo/root.json", 'object')
            .then(obj => { 
      histo = JSROOT.parse(obj);
      histo.fName = "2D";
      JSROOT.redraw('object_draw', histo, "lego2");
      console.log(obj)
    })
  </script>
```

At the backend I am doing (in Python):

```
serv = ROOT.THttpServer("http:8080")
serv.CreateServerThread()
histo = ROOT.TH2I('h1', '', 320, 0, 320, 320, 0, 320)
histo.SetName("histo")
histo.SetBinContent(40, 50, 5)
serv.Register("subfolder", histo)
```

Now I want to pass parameters to the `THttpServer` to generate dynamical histograms e.g. by parsing the filename of a (non root) data file as data source.
The [documentation](https://root.cern/doc/v624/classTRootSniffer.html#a25661502e8c3a298f967ef1ecad845b4) of `THttpServer::RegisterCommand()` mentioned parameters, corresponding I did:

```
hpx = Hpx()
serv.RegisterCommand('/test', '/hpx/.notify(arg1%,\'arg2%\')')
```

where `Hpx` is some class providing a `notify` function taking 2 parameters.
I tried call this by

```
https://subdomain.doamin.xx/root/Objects/test/root.json?arg1=1&arg2=2
```

But `Hpx::notify` is not getting called.

There is also the  kind `post_data` in [`JSROOT.httpRequest`](https://root.cern/js/latest/jsdoc/JSROOT.html#.httpRequest) but then  the `THttpServer` should not return (JSon) data.

Answer (score 1):

One should use `cmd.json` request. `root.json` returns JSON representation of requested object.

You can find more details in [THttpServer documentation](https://github.com/root-project/jsroot/blob/master/docs/HttpServer.md#commands-execution)

For the future - please submit question about ROOT framework to [ROOT forum](https://root-forum.cern.ch/).

Answer (score 0):

[See ROOT forum.](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/how-to-pass-parameters-to-thttpserver-using-python/46856/12)

```
self.__serv.RegisterCommand('/Folder/Start', TPython::Exec("do_something(\'%arg1%\')")')  # for strings
self.__serv.RegisterCommand('/Folder/Start', 'TPython::Exec("do_something(%arg1%)")') # for integers / floats
```

`def do somethings(arg1)` needs to be outside the class.